# Why do Electron applications block PowerShell when launching them from a batch script using the start command?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, electron

For reasons that I do not wish to go into further, I need to launch a batch script from a PowerShell script and wait for the batch script to complete.

Inside the batch script I would like to start an executable *asynchronously* and then exit the batch script shortly after. Once the batch script terminates, I would also want the PowerShell script to exit.

Here is a basic example of the two scripts, that does what I want:

**startExe.bat**:

```
start "" "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"

exit
```

**runStartExe.ps1** (in same directory):

```
Start-Process -FilePath "startExe.bat" -Wait;
```

In this case the *calculator* is launched and shortly after the PowerShell script terminates as expected.

However when I try do the same thing with an **Electron** based application, let's suppose you have **Visual Studio Code** installed:

**startExe.bat**:

```
start "" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"

exit
```

The PowerShell Script will be **blocked until the application** is closed.

When only the batch script is run, it exits just fine in all cases.

Why is that the case and how can I prevent it?

### Other findings

When testing this I noticed that there seems to be a difference in behavior between Windows 10 and 11. Namely when I ran `start "" "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"` in the batch script, the same locking as with electron based applications would occur in Windows 10 but not in Windows 11.
It seems in Windows 10 this would occur with every executable that has the string `!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.` embedded (most programs do, but for example the windows calculator doew not have this string), whereas in Windows 11 it would only occur with electron based programs.

I also noticed that when I introduce a `timeout 5` after starting the application and before the exit statement, the batch script would also lock for electron based applications.

Furthermore I noticed that the options [`-PassThru`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#-passthru) and [`-NoNewWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#-nonewwindow) seem to make a difference within the PowerShell script, however I was still unable to make this work reliably, especially when introducing a `timeout 5` in the batch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution requires two modifications:

- Modify your *batch file* (`.bat`) as follows, which (as you've discovered yourself) prevents `Code.exe` from printing diagnostic output to the batch file's console window:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
set ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE=1
start "" "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```

- Modify your *PowerShell* script (`.ps1`) as follows:

```bash
Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath "startExe.bat" | Wait-Process
```

- That is, make the `Start-Process` call itself *asynchronous* by removing `-Wait` and use `-PassThru` to make it emit a process-information object that [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process) then waits for.

  - If needed, you can save this process-information object and later examine the process exit code via its [`.ExitCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process.ExitCode) property.
- While this is *seemingly* functionally equivalent to just using `-Wait`, in reality it - surprisingly - is not:

  - As described in [GitHub issue #15555](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15555), `Start-Process -Wait` - unlike the `Wait-Process` cmdlet and the underlying [`.WaitForExit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit) .NET API method - waits not just for the child process *itself*, but also for *its* child processes, which causes the problem here: it also waits for the `Code.exe` process to exit.<sup>[2]</sup>

---

Note that you only need [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) in your use case if you want to execute the batch file *in a separate console window*; otherwise, *direct* invocation will do:

```bash
.\startExe.bat
```

- For *synchronous* execution in the *same window*, it is generally preferable to execute console applications (including batch files) directly: It additionally keeps their standard output streams (stdout and stderr) directly connected to PowerShell's streams, allowing you to *capture or redirect* their output; see [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.
- As an aside:

  - Direct execution itself involves waiting for the immediate child process only, as `Wait-Process` does.
  - However, if you make PowerShell *capture output* from the batch file, the entire child process *tree* is again wait for, as `Start-Process -Wait` does. That is, commands such as `$output = .\startExe.bat`, `.\startExe.bat > out.txt` and `.\startExe.bat | Measure-Object` would all cause the original problem to resurface (they would wait for `Code.exe` to terminate).

---

<sup>[1] `Code.exe` is a *GUI*(-subsystem) application, which means that no console window is created for it when it launches. However - and this is unusual for GUI applications - it detects when it is called *from a console window* and then explicitly attaches to that console and prints diagnostic output.</sup>

<sup>[2] However, in practice this is isn't a (serious) problem if a copy of Visual Studio Code happens to be running already, because the new `Code.exe` process then *delegates* to the latter and exits thereafter (this delegation process itself takes some time).</sup>

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks so much. The clear and thorough explanation also made me understand the underlying issues, which I much appreciate.

Comment: Glad to hear we got there, @frankenapps; my pleasure, and thanks for the nice feedback.